# How to create a QuickPick without input box?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have a question about the specification of QuickPick of VSCode API.
Can I create a QuickPick without an input box?

I want to use QuickPick as a dropbox - it has some items and click to run a command.

The current VSCode (version 1.84.1) has a Customize Layout panel, and it is something I want to use in my extension.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPnsq.png)

---

I have checked the web page for VSCode API.
https://code.visualstudio.com/api

I have searched whether the QuickPick has an option to hide the input box.
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/ux-guidelines/quick-picks

However, I have not found a component and options I want.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the input you see with a QuickPick is "just" a field to let the user search/filter the available QuickPick items? It is not meant to be an input that you would evaluate as the result of the interaction with a QuickPick. The QuickPick serves well as a Dropdown to run commands as you intend to.